# Find the number of people in a survey given the difference between the sizes of two groups

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this is quite easy but I would appreciate the help.

---

In a survey, children were asked if they owned a bicycle.

The results collected were:

[image]

$46$ more pupils said ‘No’ than said ‘Yes’.

Altogether, how many pupils were in the survey?

---

Comment: Well... I have tried $46$ x $8$ $= 184$ since the probabilty is out of $8$ but I don't really understand how you would do it.

Comment: Notice that the difference in the proportion of the pupils who said No and the proportion who said Yes is 2/8=1/4.

Comment: Oh ok... $46$ devided by $2$ $= 23$?

Comment: If there are $N$ pupils, then $46 = \frac{5}{8}N-\frac{3}{8}N$. Therefore $46=\frac{2}{8}N$. Therefore $N=46\cdot\frac{8}{2}=184$. BTW, this question has nothing to do with *probability* whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let x be the number of kids who said yes, and y be the number of kids who said no.

Therefore we can generate the following equations:

$$y = 46 + x$$
$$\frac{y}{x+y} = \frac{5}{8}$$
$$\frac{x}{x+y} = \frac{3}{8}$$

Now, we can say that:

$$5(x+y) = 8y$$
$$x+y = \frac{8y}{5}$$

And that

$$3(x+y) = 8x$$
$$x+y = \frac{8x}{3}$$

So,

$$\frac{8x}{3} = \frac{8y}{5}$$
$$40x = 24y$$

$$x = \frac{3y}{5}$$

Substituting this into our first equation:
$$y = 46 + \frac{3y}{5}$$
$$5y = 230 + 3y$$
$$y = 115$$
$$x = 69$$
$$x +y = 184$$

Answer (score 3):

I'll help you with setting up the problem:

$n: $ Number of students answering "no".

$y: $ Number of students answering "yes".

$x = n + y: $ Total number of students.

$y = \dfrac 38 x$

$n = \dfrac 58 x$

$n = y+46$

Three equations and three unknowns. Solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the number of students who said 'yes'. Then the number of students who said 'no' is $x+46$.

$\frac{x}{3/8}=\frac{x+46}{5/8}$

Cross-multiplying gives: $x=69$

The total number of students is: $x+x+46=2x+46=2\cdot69+46=184$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a visual method to approach the problem.

$$\begin{array}{lcc} \rm{Yeses}& \square&\square&\square &\\ \rm{Nos}&\square&\square&\square&\square &\square \end{array}$$

Each box represents the same number of students.  Since there are an additional 46 nos, the two additional boxes on the no line represent 46 students. So each box represents $\frac{46}{2}=23$ students.  So there are $8\times 23=184$ students in the survey.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in one equation. Let there is n pupils in total

5/8*n - 3/8*n  = 46

i.e. difference of pupils saying No and Yes

solving for n we get:
n = 184